# Exercise on describing a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am studying for an exam and been practicing a bit, and i can't understand this particular problem, so i was hoping i could get an explanation from someone who does.

Let $G=\langle a\rangle\times \langle b\rangle$ be a group such that $|a|=15,|b|=50$ and let $g=(a,b)\in{G}$

I need to find the subgroups of $\langle g\rangle$, the order of $g^{55}$, which i was able to find correctly, my problems comes when they ask me this:

How many elements of ord 30 are there in $G$?

How many subgroups of order 25 are in $G$?

I would really appreciate any kind of hints or advice, I have the answer sheet and it's
48 elements of ord 30 and 6 subgroups of order 25

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramino, in general for a product group $X \times Y$, the order $o(x, y)$  of $(x, y) \in X \times Y$ will be given as the least common multiple of $o(x)$ and $o(y)$ (within $X$ and $Y$, respectively). In this case, since the order of $a$ is 15, the order of $a^5$ will be 3. Likewise, the order of $b^5$ will be 10, since the order of $b$ is 50. So then we will have that $o(a^5, b^5) = lcm(3, 10) = 30$. This would be one example of an element of order 30.

You could find all of the elements of order 30 by finding integer pairs $(c, d)$ where $lcm(o(a^c), o(b^d)) = 30$. Specifically $c$ should be an integer between 0 and 14, and $d$ should be an integer between 0 and 49. One helpful thing in narrowing the search would be to apply Langrange's Theorem to see that the order of $a^c$ must be a factor of 15, and the order of $b^d$ must be a factor of 50.

A similar process would follow for finding elements of order 25. Hope this helps! If I'm not being sufficiently clear, let me know and I can give more detail.

Comment: In addition to my answer, you might also find this other post helpful, which gives a different approach to a similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601063/two-questions-about-order-of-subgroups?rq=1